# Azure Redis timeouts

Tags: azure-web-app-service, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I have a Asp.Net Azure web app calling a Azure Redis instance. I keep getting timeouts on Redis. The message I get is below.

```
 inst: 1, mgr: Inactive, err: never, queue: 120, qu: 0, qs: 120, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 65536, ar: 0, clientName: RD0004FFA37AA4, serverEndpoint: Unspecified/server.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, keyHashSlot: 11524, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=21,Free=8170,Min=200,Max=8191)
```

Both the app and redis are in the same region (East US 2).

Comment: same is happening to me.  Busy < Min (about half) in all cases, but my `in:` value is also 65536 in every timeout.  I checked my CPU on client, and was at 20% only.  this is driving us crazy trying to figure out.  was working perfectly for months, now breaks daily.  :(

Comment: @MPavlak please look at the answer below. The spikes don't show in Azure metrics. In the end we had to move all large objects out of redis. You can have a large number of keys but each object per key needs to be small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having "***in: 65536***" in your error message indicates that there are 65536 bytes sitting in the client kernel socket receive buffer ready to be processed but have not yet been parsed by the client app.

I have seen this in two cases:

1. ThreadPool settings need to be adjusted ([as described here](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/e65411214030f0d823cb#file-threadpool-md)).  However, the error message provided above does not show this as being a problem.  Check a sampling of more errors to ensure that this is not happening in other cases.
2. Client side CPU is running hot.  When the CPU is high,  the code that handles the socket receive events is not triggered in a timely manner, so the processing code does not parse the waiting data in the kernel buffer.  Check your client CPU history.  Be careful though - a short-lived spike in CPU might not show up in azure metrics because the CPU is captured on a periodic cycle (I think every 20 seconds).  If the spike happens between those samples and is short, it might not be noticed by the metrics gathering system.

Other common [client-side causes are documented here](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/db0e90bedeb3fc4823c2#file-diagnoserediserrors-clientside-md) and [common server-side errors are documented here](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/9225f783a40564c9879d#file-diagnoserediserrors-serverside-md).

Comment: I increased the worker treads based on the documentation so that is not the issue. Could be CPU like you said and it doesnt show up in Azure metrics. Will see if I can find anything there.

Comment: One sure-fire way to get CPU usage at the time of the timeout is to capture a dump of the process.

Comment: This is an Azure app service so not sure how I would do that. For now we are not using Redis to store large collections.

Comment: Check out the instructions here (I think they are still accurate): https://gist.github.com/JonCole/aa1c732b77bf4ce28d3d#azure-app-service-websites

Comment: Thanks will try that next time I see that error. Iits not happening anymore now that we moved the large objects out of Redis.